# MDX - Count of Filtered CROSSJOIN - Performance Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx, cross-join

**BACKGROUND:** I've been using MDX for a bit but I am by no means an expert at it - looking for some performance help. I'm working on a set of "Number of Stores Authorized / In-Stock / Selling / Etc" calculated measures (MDX) in a SQL Server Analysis Services 2012 Cube. I had these calculations performing well originally, but discovered that they weren't aggregating across my product hierarchy the way I needed them to. The two hierarchies predominantly used in this report are Business -> Item and Division -> Store.

For example, in the original MDX calcs the Stores In-Stock measure would perform correctly at the "Item" level but wouldn't roll up a proper sum to the "Business" level above it. At the business level, we want to see the total number of store/product combinations in-stock, not a distinct or MAX value as it appeared to do originally.

**ORIGINAL QUERY RESULTS:** Here's an example of it *NOT* working correctly (imagine this is an Excel Pivot Table):

```
[FILTER: CURRENT WEEK DAYS]
[BUSINESS]          [AUTH. STORES]  [STORES IN-STOCK]   [% OF STORES IN STOCK]
[+] Business One    2,416           2,392               99.01%
[-] Business Two    2,377           2,108               93.39%
    -Item 1         2,242           2,094               99.43%
    -Item 2         2,234           1,878               84.06%
    -Item 3         2,377           2,108               88.68%
    -Item N         ...             ...                 ...
```

**FIXED QUERY RESULTS:** After much trial and error, I switched to using a filtered count of a CROSSJOIN() of the two hierarchies using the DESCENDANTS() function, which yielded the correct numbers (below):

```
[FILTER: CURRENT WEEK DAYS]
[BUSINESS]          [AUTH. STORES]  [STORES IN-STOCK]   [% OF STORES IN STOCK]
[+] Business One    215,644         149,301             93.90%
[-] Business Two    86,898          55,532              83.02%
    -Item 1         2,242           2,094               99.43%
    -Item 2         2,234           1,878               99.31%
    -Item 3         2,377           2,108               99.11%
    -Item N         ...             ...                 ...
```

**QUERY THAT NEEDS HELP:** Here is the "new" query that yields the results above:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Num Stores In-Stock]
AS COUNT(
    FILTER(
        CROSSJOIN(
            DESCENDANTS(
                [Product].[Item].CURRENTMEMBER,
                [Product].[Item].[UPC]        
            ),
            DESCENDANTS(
                [Division].[Store].CURRENTMEMBER,
                [Division].[Store].[Store ID]       
            )
        ),
        [Measures].[Inventory Qty] > 0
    )
), 
FORMAT_STRING = "#,#", 
NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Inventory Qty] },
```

This query syntax is used in a bunch of other "Number of Stores Selling / Out of Stock / Etc."-type calculated measures in the cube, with only a variation to the [Inventory Qty] condition at the bottom or by chaining additional conditions.

In its current condition, this query can take 2-3 minutes to run which is way too long for the audience of this reporting. Can anyone think of a way to reduce the query load or help me rewrite this to be more efficient?

Thank you!

---

**UPDATE 2/24/2014:** We solved this issue by bypassing a lot of the MDX involved and adding flag values to our named query in the DSV.

For example, instead of doing a filter command in the MDX code for "number of stores selling" - we simply added this to the fact table named query...

```
CASE WHEN [Sales Qty] > 0 
    THEN 1 
    ELSE NULL 
END AS [Flag_Selling]
```

...then we simply aggregated these measures as LastNonEmpty in the cube. They roll up much faster than the full-on MDX queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be much faster to model your conditions into the cube, avoiding the slow `Filter` function:

If there are just a handful of conditions, add an attribute for each of them with two values, one for condition fulfilled, say "cond: yes", and one for condition not fulfilled, say "cond: no". You can define this in a view on the physical fact table, or in the DSV, or you can model it physically. These attributes can be added to the fact table directly, defining a dimension on the same table, or more cleanly as a separate dimension table referenced from the fact table. Then define your measure as

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Num Stores In-Stock]
AS COUNT(
    CROSSJOIN(
        DESCENDANTS(
            [Product].[Item].CURRENTMEMBER,
            [Product].[Item].[UPC]        
        ),
        DESCENDANTS(
            [Division].[Store].CURRENTMEMBER,
            [Division].[Store].[Store ID]       
        ),
        { [Flag dim].[cond].[cond: yes] }

    )
)
```

Possibly, you even could define the measure as a standard count measure of the fact table.

In case there are many conditions, it might make sense to add just a single attribute with one value for each condition as a many-to-many relationship. This will be slightly slower, but still faster than the `Filter` call.

Comment: This data is also bound by time, so adding an attribute to the dimension wouldn't work necessarily...however I thought about a binary flag to the fact table in the DSV like you mentioned. I may try that and report back.

Comment: We went ahead and modeled the conditions into the cube as you recommended and it's working about 5x faster. Guess we were trying to get too fancy with the MDX!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can avoid the cross join as well as filter completely. Try using this:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Num Stores In-Stock]
AS
CASE WHEN [Product].[Item Name].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Product].[Item Name].[All]
THEN 
SUM(EXISTS([Product].[Item Name].[Item Name].MEMBERS,[Business].[Business Name].CURRENTMEMBER),
COUNT(
EXISTS(
    [Division].[Store].[Store].MEMBERS,
    (
        [Business].[Business Name].CURRENTMEMBER,
        [Product].[Item Name].CURRENTMEMBER
    ),
    "Measure Group Name"
)
))
ELSE
COUNT(
EXISTS(
    [Division].[Store].[Store].MEMBERS,
    (
        [Business].[Business Name].CURRENTMEMBER,
        [Product].[Item Name].CURRENTMEMBER
    ),
    "Measure Group Name"
)
)
END
```

I tried it using a dimension in my cube and using Area-Subsidiary hierarchy.
The case statement handles the situation of viewing data at Business level. Basically, the `SUM()` across all members of Item Names used in `CASE` statement calculates values for individual Item Names and then sums up all the values. I believe this is what you needed.